# Message: unlink(/tmp/ci_session0189a7f1c86eb18fb70afcfedc2d5040e9c23146): Operation not permitted

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am getting error not regularly but after time intervals:

> Message:
>   unlink(/tmp/ci_session0189a7f1c86eb18fb70afcfedc2d5040e9c23146):
>   Operation not permitted

In config I tried:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

Also tried:-

In config:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASE_URL.'application/temp/';
```

also changed the permission of it `(755 & 777)`

Though not getting resolved..

Answer (score 0):

Use FCPATH or APPPATH

Location *application > temp*

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'temp/';
```

OR

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/temp/';
```

> ***Folder permission for sessions 0700***

```
EXT: The PHP file extension
FCPATH: Path to the front controller (this file) (root of CI)
SELF: The name of THIS file (index.php)
BASEPATH: Path to the system folder
APPPATH: The path to the "application" folder
```

Comment: I tried: $config['sess_save_path'] = BASE_URL.'application/temp/'; & $config['sess_save_path'] = BASE_URL.'temp/'; and temp folder is in both places with (777-permissions), though not working

Comment: I updated it. dont use 0777 for folder permission when for session. And base url not for session path either.